# Integral of Legendre Polynomials over half space

Tags: integration, legendre-polynomials

I am wondering if there is a way to compute the following integral:

$\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\left[P_0(\cos\theta)P_k(\cos\theta)\sin(\theta)d\theta\right]$

I have very little experience working with Legendre Polynomials and I am not sure how to approach this situation. I have found formulas for calculating them over a half-interval, however, I am not sure how it changes when the scale factor: $\sin\theta$ is introduced.

Comment: Change of variabel $t=cos(\theta$ leads to $dt= -sin(\theta) d\theta$ and we get $$ \int_{-1}^0P_0(t)P_k(t) dt$$. Hoppfully this helgs

Comment: Yes, thank you!